# Why is my array comparison not printing in MIPS?

Tags: mips

Here is my code that calculates the sum of two arrays and then prints them in a message to the the console. I would now like to compare my two array sums and return the correct message prompt depending on which array is larger. I feel like I'm very close because I tried to follow the logic from the first printed statements but how can I compare register $s7 & $s8 and then declare one the larger array through my message prompt I have set up? I'm using this emulator: https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=mipsr5-spim

```
.data

x:          .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
iterator:   .word 0
size:       .word 9

prompt:     .asciiz "The total sum of the array is equal to: "

.text
main:

la $s0, prompt
la $t0, x
lw $t1, iterator
lw $t2, size

begin_loop:
bgt $t1, $t2, exit_loop

sll $t3, $t1, 2

addu $t3, $t3, $t0

lw $t6, 0($t3)

addu $s7, $s7, $t6

addi $t1, $t1, 1

j begin_loop

exit_loop:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 1
la $a0, ($s7)
syscall

.data

x2:         .word 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
iterator2:  .word 0
size2:      .word 9

prompt2:        .asciiz "The total sum of array 2 is equal to: "
prompt3:        .asciiz "The larger array is array 1"
prompt4:        .asciiz "The larger array is array 2"

.text
main2:

la $s0, prompt2
la $t0, x2
lw $t1, iterator2
lw $t2, size2

begin_loop2:
bgt $t1, $t2, exit_loop2

sll $t3, $t1, 2

addu $t3, $t3, $t0

lw $t6, 0($t3)

addu $s8, $s8, $t6

addi $t1, $t1, 1

j begin_loop2

exit_loop2:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

li $v0, 1
la $a0, ($s8)
syscall
slt $t1,$s7,$s8      # checks if $s0 > $s1
beq $t1,1,prompt3     # if $s7 > $s8, goes to prompt3
beq $t1,$zero,prompt4 # if $s8 < $s7, goes to prompt4
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt4
syscall
```

Comment: `b` (beq, ...) "branch" goes to a label which is a place in the code. What is at label prompt3? You want to jump into the acsii string and start executing that?

Comment: I have updated my code so that prompt3 and prompt4 are under the correct .data region of the code under prompt2. Now I think Lines 56 and 57 need to reference new labels (that I don’t have) so they jump to the correct points of output. These new labels should be changed which is fairly simple, but how and where do I declare these new labels?